# Sorting mysql results by several columns

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I'm building a tournament system and need to sort the teams depending on two criteria:

1. Points (2 points for winning a series of 3 games)
2. Difference in games (games won - lost)

Now I have one table column for points, one for individual games won and one for individual games lost.

I get the results from the database sorted by points (ORDER BY points DESC). The problem comes with the individual rankings. If team A and team B has the same amount of points, but team B has a higher, positive, difference between games won and games lost, then team B is to be ranked higher then team A.

Since all the games won't be played the same time, and some teams might be behind on their schedule, a completely possible scenario is one team having more wins then the other but a worse difference.

Now the only solution I've been able to come up with is the following:

1. Get the data from the DB (sorted by points)
2. Count the number of occurrences of each points value (example: 9pts.x2, 7pts.x5...)
3. Make the number of arrays needed according to step 2.
4. Sort the data into these arrays, again depending on the points value.
5. If the length of an array is longer then 1, sort it on the difference between games won and games lost.
6. Print the end result.

This seems VERY inefficient to me. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
select name, wins, losses, points, (wins - losses) as "diff"
from teams
order by points desc, diff desc
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ea97/1

Comment: Oh wow, didn't think you could use arithmetics in mysql-calls like that. Thanks a lot!